# K8s client is returning page not found when trying to create custom namespace object

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-blob-storage, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

I have used following json for custom namespace object in kubernetes.

```
 const azureIdentityJson = {
          'apiVersion': 'aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1',
          'kind': 'AzureIdentity',
          'metadata': {
            'name': identityName,
            'namespace': namespace,
            'annotations': {
              'aadpodidentity.k8s.io/Behavior': 'namespaced'
            }
          },
          'spec': {
            'type': 0,
            'resourceID': managedIdentityId,
            'clientID': managedIdentityClientId
          }
      };
await k8sClient.createCustomObject('aadpodidentity.k8s.io', 'v1', 'azureidentities', azureIdentityJson);
```

and createCustomObject function is as follows.

```
 public async createCustomObject (customTypeName: string, customVersion: string, plural: string, customObjectManifest: any): Promise<any> {
const client = this.kubeConfig.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi);
return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
  client.createNamespacedCustomObject(customTypeName, customVersion, customObjectManifest.metadata.namespace ? customObjectManifest.metadata.namespace : 'default', plural, customObjectManifest).then(
    (response) => {
        resolve(response);
    },
    (err) => {
      reject(err.response && err.response.body ? err.response.body : err);
    },
  );
});
```

}

when executing, getting 404, page not found error. No other information were there. It was working fine earlier. Please help here. Stuck almost a month now.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

CustomResources store structured data in custom fields likebuilt-in fields `apiVersion, kind and metadata`, which are explicitly validated by the api.There might be issue among one of these.

Try to upgrade Aks version or node js version.

> custom resource objects must sometimes be converted between the
> version they are stored at and the version they are served at. If the
> conversion involves schema changes and requires custom logic, a
> conversion webhook should be used. If there are no schema changes, the
> default None conversion strategy may be used and only the apiVersion
> field will be modified when serving different versions.

[Versions in CustomResourceDefinitions | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definition-versioning/#:%7E:text=This%20example%20shows%20a%20CustomResourceDefinition%20with%20two%20versions)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all parameters in createNamespacedCustomObject are set correcly.
Also plurar name must match the value in the CRD. You can check the value using this command:

`kubectl describe crd <your-custom-type> | grep Plural`